# VS Code Remove Sidebar Titles Symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, sidebar

Good morning.
In a markdown file, is it possible to remove the title icons (#, ##, ###, ####) in the sidebar?
They are really annoying. Spaces are enough to indicate the level of text.
Thank you.

https://ibb.co/XYRdwzz

Comment: Did you take that picture? Can you zoom it out some more?

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.61.1, this is not possible.

However, there is an open issue about this on VS Code's official GitHub:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53992

There are proposals for a solution already. Maybe someone might pick this up and implement a configuration option for it.